# Using SQL to Perform a Left Join from a Named Range to a database ADODB

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to know how in excel VBA using SQL to Perform a Left Join from a Named Range to a database ADODB table.

Thank you for your help,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40054856/adodb-sql-syntax-access-table-inner-join-with-excel-worksheet